# using wysiwyg Editor text with angular2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, wysiwyg

I'm trying to use wysiwyg in my project angular2 
when I add my code in index.html page (on the root page, it works)

but when I try to use it in a child view html it doesn't get the css or (and) javascript code to get my wysiwyg correctly

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Arkloud Adservio</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
    <!-- Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <!--bootsrat https-->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/loginCss.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/froala_editor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/froala_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/plugins/code_view.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/plugins/colors.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/plugins/emoticons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/plugins/image_manager.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/plugins/image.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/plugins/line_breaker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/plugins/table.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/plugins/char_counter.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/plugins/video.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.3.0/codemirror.min.css">


    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
        }

        div#editor {
            width: 81%;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
<div id="editor">
    <form>
      <textarea id='edit' style="margin-top: 30px;" placeholder="Type some text">
        <h1>Textarea</h1>
        <p>The editor can also be initialized on a textarea.</p>
      </textarea>

        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    System.config({
                      packages: {
                          app: {
                              format: 'register',
                              defaultExtension: 'js'
                          }
                      }
                  });
    System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.3.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.3.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/align.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/code_beautifier.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/code_view.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/colors.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/draggable.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/emoticons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/font_size.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/font_family.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/image.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/image_manager.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/line_breaker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/link.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/lists.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/paragraph_format.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/paragraph_style.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/table.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/video.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/url.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/entities.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/char_counter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/inline_style.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/save.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#edit').froalaEditor({
                                    fullPage: true,
                                    toolbarBottom: false
                                })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in this case it works (I put my wysiwyg in my `index.html`)

but when i put this on another view component it doesn't work

```
<div id="editor">
        <form>
          <textarea id='edit' style="margin-top: 30px;" placeholder="Type some text">
            <h1>Textarea</h1>
            <p>The editor can also be initialized on a textarea.</p>
          </textarea>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://www.tinymce.com/

If angular 2 Use Tinymce .. [Why tinymce?](https://www.silverstripe.org/blog/why-tinymce/)

```
 //.ts
 import {EditorDirectory} from '/../directives';
 @Component({
 selector: 'Foo'
 directives: [EditorDirectory],
 template: '<textarea [htmlEditor]="Form.find('Text')"></textarea>'
 })

 // Tinymce directive 
 @Directive({
 inputs: ['htmlEditor'],
 selector: '[htmlEditor]'
 })

 tinymce.init({
    selector: '.tinymce-editor',
    schema: 'html5',
  });
```

Index.html

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });

</script>
```

Remaining can read from [Tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/)

Comment: I download tinymce then i should add files within my project !
How to get tinymce ?

Comment: In package.json angular file add in dependencies // "dependencies": {"tinymce": "4.3.12"} }, and then in terminal add npm install tinymce

Comment: How to use this after angular 2 official release? @mayur

Answer (score 13):

I agree with @mayur to use angular2 and tinyMCE.
If you need more guidance on the HOW based on @mayur's answer:

directives/tiny.directive.ts:

```
import {Directive} from '@angular/core';
declare var tinymce: any;
// Tinymce directive
@Directive({
    inputs: ['htmlEditor'],
    selector: '[htmlEditor]'
    })

export class EditorDirective{
    constructor(){
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea', //change this to a specific class/id
            schema: 'html5',
        });
    }
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {EditorDirective} from './directives/tiny.directive';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [EditorDirective],
    templateUrl: '<textarea [htmlEditor]></textarea>'    //having [htmlEditor]="Form.find('Text')" caused an error for me, your mileage may vary
    })
export class AppComponent {

}
```

main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent  } from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--include title/metadata etc. here-->

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!--
    include libraries here
    follow angular2 quickstart for help
    tinymce may require a jquery import here
    -->
    <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });

    </script>
    <!--don't forget styles!-->
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    </div>
</body>
```

hope this helps

Comment: This is not working on router pages. what we need to do for router pages ?

Comment: Wouldn't the app module need to have the directive imported?

Comment: I haven't updated this since Angular 2 official release; will try get back to it at some point!
The biggest change would be as @Jon said, the app module needing to import the directive instead of in the component.

Comment: EditorDirective should be present in declarations in app.module.ts @chris.currin

Comment: Is this module compatible with AOT compilation ? There are no d.ts files for typescript. Have you built with AOT ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full explanation with steps.

1. Install:

   ```
   npm install --save tinymce
   ```
2. In file give the path for tinymce script files

   ```
   "scripts": [
       "../node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.js",
       "../node_modules/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js",
       "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.js",
       "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.js",
       "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.js"
    ],
   ```
3. Run the following command it will copy the styles inside the assests folder.

   ```
   xcopy /I /E node_modules\tinymce\skins src\assets\skins
   ```
4. Create directive for tinymce so it will be used anywhere in the application.

   ```
    import { Directive,  
         EventEmitter,
         Input,
         Output, ElementRef,OnInit,
         AfterViewInit,  OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';


       declare var tinymce:any

       @Directive({
         selector: '[htmlEditor]'
       })
       export class SimpleTinyMceDirective implements OnInit,OnDestroy{

         private htmlContent:any;
         private editor;
         @Output() private htmlEditorKeyUp : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

         constructor(private el:ElementRef){

         }


         ngOnInit(){
            tinymce.init({
             selector: '#' + this.el.nativeElement.id,
             plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table'],
             skin_url: 'assets/skins/lightgray',
             setup: editor => {
               this.editor = editor;
               editor.on('keyup', () => {
                 const content = editor.getContent();
                 this.htmlEditorKeyUp.emit(content);
               });
             },
           });
         }


         ngOnDestroy() {
           tinymce.remove(this.editor);
         }
       }
   ```

   save it as simple-tinymce.directive.ts
5. Now inside the app.module.ts file

   ```
   import * as tinymce from 'tinymce'; //"importing tinymce"
   import {SimpleTinyMceDirective} from './common/simple-tinymce/simple-tinymce.directive'; //import the directive your path of directive may be different than mine.
   ```
6. You can use like below inside the component template

   ```
   <textarea  id="description" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Enter the description" required [(ngModel)]='description' #description='ngModel' 
       (htmlEditorKeyUp)="onHtmlEditorKeyUp($event)" htmlEditor></textarea>
   ```
7. You can fetch inside the component.ts like below

   ```
   onHtmlEditorKeyUp(content:any):void{
       console.log(content);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answers but i couldn't get this working, maybe because i'm using routing and the dom element where to apply the directive is not already available. I just moved the tinymce.init code from the constructor to the ngOnInit function and now it works as expected:

directives/tiny.directive.ts:

```
import {Directive, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
declare var tinymce: any;

// Tinymce directive
@Directive({
    inputs: ['htmlEditor'],
    selector: '[htmlEditor]'
})
export class EditorDirective implements OnInit { }

ngOnInit(){
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea', //change this to a specific class/id
        schema: 'html5',
    });
}
```