# ng2-ckeditor not working in angular2 app? Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to use the ng2-ckeditor component in my angular2 application, but for some reason i keep getting an error in console saying

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined

Here is the code i have.

system.config.json

```
(function(global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
        'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
        'angular2-tree-component':    'node_modules/angular2-tree-component',
        'lodash':                     'node_modules/lodash',
        'ng2-ckeditor':               'node_modules/ng2-ckeditor'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                      { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                     { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-tree-component' : { main: 'dist/angular2-tree-component.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'lodash' :                  { main: 'lodash.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng2-ckeditor' :            { main: 'lib/CKEditor.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade'
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

content.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from './models/content';
import { CKEditor } from 'ng2-ckeditor';

@Component({
    selector: 'content',
    template: '<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="content.text" [config]="{ uiColor: '#99000' }" debounce="500"></ckeditor>',
    directives: [ CKEditor ]
})

export class ContentComponent {

    @Input()
    content: Content;

    active: number = 1;
    sizes: number[] = [ 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1 ];

    getAnchor() {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Can also see here that in my Network tab, the CKEditor.js file is being loaded.

[image]

Anyone have any idea why this isnt working?

Comment: Refer this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/37526911/5868331

Answer (score 1):

This means that your CKEDITOR JavaScript didn't load.

The file `CKEditor.js` refers to the Angular2 component which doesn't contain the editor itself. That file is [part of the repo](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/blob/master/lib/CKEditor.js).

So you need to include [ckeditor.js](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/standard/ckeditor.js) yourself.

I'm not sure about the condition on [line 159](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/blob/master/lib/CKEditor.js#L159), which should detect missing CKEDITOR JavaScripts. Maybe show the entire error message on what line inside `CKEditor.js` it throws the error.

Comment: I have now installed CKEditor via npm `npm install ckeditor --save`. Can i load this via systemjs as well?

Comment: I'm sure you can't. CKEditor doesn't support any module system so you have to include it with `<script>`.