# CKEditor erase the content of tag (div) inline mode - Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, ckeditor

When I add the CKEditor in my tag (div) it crush the content of this tag
why it erase the content !!
this is my Directive CKEditor

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit,Directive} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({

    selector: 'div[ckeditorContent]'
})
export class CKEditor implements OnInit {
    @Input() ckeditorContent:string;

    constructor(private _elm:ElementRef) {

        CKEDITOR.inline(_elm.nativeElement);
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to use editor with angular 2 i will prefer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37526911/5868331

Comment: have you any plunker code please ? or web site of this editor thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer thanks for making my answer improve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523403/using-wysiwyg-editor-text-with-angular2/37526911#37526911