# How to integrate inline editor plugin (or other plugins) in angular 2 project via webpack

Tags: angular, plugins, webpack

I am using **webpack** (instead of **systemJS.config.js**) for Angular2 project, I am in confusion how to integrate inline editor plugin(or other plugins). could you guys help me?

My **webpack** folder structure is like below

**webpack**

->webpack.common.js

->webpack.dev.js

->webpack.prod.js

->webpack.vendor.js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37526911/5868331

Comment: What do you mean by inline editor? Anyway, SystemJS is better go back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am working with JHipster Angular 2 project, Jhipster is generating webpack to replace the SystemJS

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link for webpack configuration.

```
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html
```

Comment: Thank you vignesh, could you share any example document/video to add third party plugin.