# How to set html content as value in simpleMDE texteditor in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, simplemde

I am having value which contains HTML tags in it. I want to render it as initial value of SimpleMDE editor.
I have tried

```
simplemde.value(content)
```

But it just render it as simple RAW data with all the HTML tags displaying in texteditor field area.
If possible suggest some solution compatible with angular2.

Comment: try this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2

Comment: Can use http://stackoverflow.com/a/37526911/5868331