# How to set html content as value in simpleMDE texteditor

Tags: javascript, simplemde

I am having value which contains HTML tags in it. I want to render it as initial value of SimpleMDE editor. I have tried

```
simplemde.value(content)
```

But it just render it as simple RAW data with all the HTML tags displaying in texteditor field area.

Comment: Similar question asked here. But its for angular2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084091/how-to-set-html-content-as-value-in-simplemde-texteditor-in-angular2